# "from sqlalchemy import event" not working

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm getting an error:

```
MacBook-Pro:microblog_3 olehdubno$ python db_create.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_create.py", line 5, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "/Users/olehdubno/Desktop/microblog_3/app/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py", line 81, in load_module
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb.tb_next)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import orm, event
ImportError: cannot import name event
```

I'm working on Part IV: Database: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database.

My github code: https://github.com/odubno/microblog.

Anything I do, I cannot get event imported. Simply trying `from sqlalchemy import event` doesn't work either.

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-Restless==0.17.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.0
Flask-WTF==0.11
GraphLab-Create==1.1
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow==2.7.0
SQLAlchemy==0.6.8
Tempita==0.5.2
WTForms==2.0.2
Werkzeug==0.10.1
argparse==1.2.1
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
blaze==0.6.0
boto==2.33.0
daemonize==2.3.1
decorator==3.4.0
folium==0.1.2
geopy==1.4.0
george==0.2.1
ggplot==0.6.5
itsdangerous==0.24
librato-metrics==0.4.9
mimerender==0.5.5
mixpanel-py==3.1.1
nltk==3.0.0
nose==1.3.4
numpy==1.8.2
oauthlib==0.7.2
pandas==0.14.1
patsy==0.3.0
prettytable==0.7.2
psycopg2==2.5.4
pyparsing==2.0.3
pyshp==1.2.1
python-dateutil==2.4.1
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
pytz==2014.7
requests==2.3.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.2
scikit-learn==0.15.1
six==1.9.0
sqlalchemy-migrate==0.7.2
suds==0.4
sympy==0.7.5
textblob==0.9.0
tornado==3.2.1
twitter==1.15.0
vboxapi==1.0
virtualenv==1.11.6
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.9.3
xlwt==0.7.5
```

Answer (score 4):

[Events were added](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/event.html) to SQLAlchemy in version 0.7. You are using version 0.6.8. Upgrading will fix your `ImportError`.

```
pip install -U sqlalchemy
```

Version 0.7 was released several years ago. 0.9.9 is the most recent (at the time of this answer). Unless you have a specific need for 0.6, upgrading should be well worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `pip install -U sqlalchemy` and weirdly it still didn't resolve the issue.

What did work and I forgot to use was the virtualenv.

Once I activated my virtualenv in terminal using:

```
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
New python executable in venv/bin/python
Installing distribute.........done.
Installing pip................done.
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)$ python
```

I followed up by:

```
pip install sqlalchemy
```

Following the tutorial, I installed the rest of the extensions in virtualenv and everything works now.